# How to join lines without producing a space?

Tags: whitespace, line-breaks

The standard <kbd>J</kbd> command for joining lines replaces the newline character(s) with a space. It's useful when editing 'literature' but can be troublesome if I, say, edit a hex dump by hand if I forget to remove the superfluous space.

Is there a quick & easy method to join two lines without producing a space between them?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The `gJ` mapping does this; from `:help gJ`:

> Join [count] lines, with a minimum of two lines. Don't insert or remove any spaces.

You could rebind it to `J`, if you want to save a keystroke:

```
:nnoremap J gJ
```

Note that this doesn't *remove* any spaces, so if either the current line ends with a space or next line starts with one or more spaces they will be left as is; so this:

```
Hello
    world
```

Becomes:

```
Hello    world
```

We could use `Jx` in this case, then it will be `Helloworld`, but that won't work in all cases; from the help:

> Join the highlighted lines, with a minimum of two lines.  Remove the indent and insert up to two
>   spaces
>
> [...]
>
> These commands, except "gJ", insert one space in place of the  unless
>   there is trailing white space or the next line starts with a ')'.

So in some cases more than one space or no space is inserted. As far as I can
see, there is no easy way to change this behaviour; I created a function to
modify `gJ` to always join without spaces:

```
" Like gJ, but always remove spaces
fun! s:join_spaceless()
    execute 'normal! gJ'

    " Remove character under the cursor if it's whitespace.
    if matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') =~ '\s'
        execute 'normal! dw'
    endif
endfun

" Map it to a key
nnoremap <Leader>J :call <SID>join_spaceless()<CR>
```

If you want, you can add `let save = winsaveview()` at the start of the function, and `call winrestview(save)` at the end to prevent the cursor from moving (but the current behaviour is the same as `gJ`).

See also: `:help J`, `:help 'joinspaces'`

Comment: Is it possible to use some "Preserve" function to keep the cursor position when using this function or how do I get this result?

Comment: Very late reply @SergioAraujo, but yeah, you can use `let save = winsavesave()` at the start, and `winrestview(save)` at the end.

Comment: `normal! "_dw` would prevent the deleted whitespace from stomping your @" register. Execute doesn't seem necessary for the two normal commands. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Unfortunately does not work from visual mode with multiple lines selected, only the last line join will have spaces removed :/

Answer (score 12):

Another trick you may try is to use replace. Sometimes this might be useful.

```
%s/$\n//g
```

Scenario: Delete the last character and join with the next line:

```
%s/=$\n\(.\)/\1/g
```

For example,

```
xxxx=
123
```

becomes:

```
xxxx123
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a macro and reuse it:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

Now replay the macro, `a` by using <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> wherever you want to join two lines with no space.

<kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd> will repeat the previous macro. So you can just hold <kbd>@</kbd> to join multiple lines.

Comment: Why type `@a` when you can type `Jx`? Same number of key presses and SHIFT presses!

Comment: @Shahbaz Maybe because of the last line: "you can just hold @"

Comment: @muru, that's true!

Comment: It also makes it a repeatable command, so you can use `3@a` to join 3 lines, whereas doing `3Jx` would join 3 lines with spaces and then delete the space between the second and third lines, leaving spaces between the other lines.

Answer (score 4):

To always join with a single space :

```
nmap J gJi <ESC>ciW <ESC>
```

To join with no space at all (removes trailing+leading space) :

```
nmap <C-J> gJi <ESC>diW
```

Comment: Welcome to this site! Your mappings look a bit over-engineered to me, it would be helpful if you could add a bit more explanations about how they work.

Comment: `gJ` joins the lines, bringing leading whitespace with them: `Hello|    world` (the cursor is after Hello) Then `i <ESC>` enters insert mode, inserts a space, then escapes back to normal mode. Then `ciW <ESC>` is the "change in word" command, followed by a space, which replaces all the whitespace after the cursor, then escapes back to normal mode. `Hello world`

Answer (score 2):

Select the lines you'd like to merge, enter an **Ex** command by typing a colon `:` in normal mode. Then type this command:

`s/$\n\s*//gc`

The entire command should look likewise:

`:'<,'>s/$\n\s*//gc`

> This is actually a tweaked version of the [@insidepower's command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4420/25135) that replaces space-indentations as well as newline characters.

**Explanation:**

- `'<,'>` means that we modify only the lines selected in visual mode.
- `/$\n\s*` is a *regex* pattern. We're looking for a match that ends `$` with a new line character `\n` and has non-determined number of whitespaces `*` thereafter.
- `s/pattern//gc` is a substitute command to find each *pattern* and replace it with  an empty character on confirmation.

> To figure out more about flags and metacharacters for regular expressions in Vim take a look at [this chapter of Vim Reference.](https://learnbyexample.gitbooks.io/vim-reference/content/Regular_Expressions.html)

Comment: Hi ubique, welcome to [vi.se]! You've got a pretty well-written answer there; kudos for that. My one nitpick is that vim regular expressions =/= python regular expressions, and sometimes that is confusing for users. Maybe link to the help document for Vim regex instead?

Comment: Second nit: the answer you reference was written by @[insidepower](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/3240/insidepower) and edited by Peter.

Comment: This solution is almost perfect! add `:keeppatterns` before to keep the search untouched. Also it joins 1 line too much compared to J in visual mode, apart from that it's great!