# How to delete line endings in Vim?

Tags: multiple-lines

Suppose I have **several words** on **multiple lines**:

```
R            
T_std       
k_AB_IN      
k_AB_ac      
k_AB_co2     
k_La
```

Now I want them to have them **all on one line**, only seperated by one whitespace.

```
R T_std ... k_La
```

So effectively, I need to **delete all line endings**. Maybe this could be done by recording a macro (like `0dhj`) and subsequently applying it to all lines, but there needs to a better way!?

(All I have found on the web so far was [how to remove extra whitespace](https://coderwall.com/p/m4083g/removing-whitespace-with-vim) via regular expressions, but not line endings.)

Comment: In your example there is some trailing whitespace after the text; is it like that in the actual file or is that just in the example here?

Comment: not quite the same, but should give you a good overview of options: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/439/how-to-join-lines-without-producing-a-space

Comment: @MartinTournoij It is, because there used to be a block of `= vector(1)` and so on, which I deleted via Visual Block mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove line endings by *joining* lines together. There are a few commands that can accomplish this, for instance the [`J`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#J) Normal-mode command will join the current line and the next, or you can use a count to join more than the two lines, or use `J` in Visual mode to join all lines spanning the selection.

(The `:join` command that @D.BenKnoble mentioned and that takes a range is analogous to the `J` Normal-mode command, so that's an option too.)

The `J` command will add spaces between the joined lines (which, from your example, is what you want.) If you for some reason *don't* want to add spaces in between the joined lines, you can use [`gJ`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#gJ) instead. (Or, if you're using the Ex command, you can use `:join!` with an extra `!` at the end.)

When `J` is adding spaces in between joined lines, in some situations it will add two spaces, when the initial line ends in a period, question mark, exclamation mark. You can control this behavior with the [`'joinspaces'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27joinspaces%27) option, which is on by default (the behavior of conditionally adding two spaces), but you can disable with `:set nojoinspaces`.

---

Finally, if you want to use a `:substitute` command to replace the newlines (instead of one of the join command variants), you can use [`\n`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cn) to match the newline, and replacing it will also have the effect of joining lines together.

The following `:substitute` command is similar to `:%join`:

```
:%s/\n/ /
```

Except that the `:s` command will not respect the `'joinspaces'` behavior and it will add a space to the last line in the buffer (you could use a range of `:1,$-1` to avoid that last part.)

Using a `:s` command matching a `\n` can be useful when you want to replace the newline with something other than a space, or otherwise collapse whitespace preceding the newlines, or perhaps only join consecutive blank lines, situations where using regexes give you a lot more flexibility than a command such as `J` that can only do one thing.

Answer (score 4):

I think there’s a substitute command that works, but the first thing that comes to mind is

```
:%join
```

Which translates to “join the whole file.”

Answer (score 0):

After trying out several commands, I've noticed that the trailing whitespace is indeed a problem, so I also need to remove it.

When I combine [your answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28476/32139) and the expression from [this post](https://coderwall.com/p/m4083g/removing-whitespace-with-vim), I arrive at:

```
:%s/\s\+$\n/ /
```

which does exactly what I want.

Comment: You don't need the `$`, matching on `\n` will take care of only matching at the end of the line. You might want to use `\s*` instead, to also join lines not ending in trailing whitespace. Finally, you might want to use `:1,$-1` as a range to avoid adding a space to the last line (though it's easy to drop that one in a second step.)