# Replace regex group in nvim

Tags: regular-expression, replace, nvim

I'm using the most recent version of nvim on arch.

I have sentences in my text like this

> The
> brown fox

I wish to use this format
`:%s///g`
to replace all lines starting
`\nlowercase letter + rest of line` with
`lowercase letter + rest of line`

ie shift the line starting lowercase up to be joined to the line above it, like using the "J" key.

Result should be like this

> The brown fox

Want to do this for all sentences globally.

How can I do this in Vim?

Comment: Highly related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/28470/10604

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure a very similar question was already asked here. Anyway, here's a simple trick:

```
:g/^\l/-join
```

That is, for every line starting with lowercase letter join it with the previous one.

Comment: thanks, that is indeed a neat solution

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked

`:%s/\n\([a-z]\)/ \1/g`

I am familiar with the
`%s///g`
format but had previously struggled, for whatever reason with putting regex into vim's search and replace command.
Don't know why becasue as I now see it's as easy as any other regex substitution.

Comment: Nice one! A few simplifications are possible: `:%s/\n\ze\l/ /`. I usually like to use `\zs` and `\ze` to mark start and end of match, I find them to be a lot more convenient than using groups and backreferences...

Answer (score 0):

It just happened to me. Thanks @matt for the solution. I changed for my usage

```
:g/^[^0-9]/-join
```

^[^0-9] - any line that starting with non-number character

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt arguably it is an answer, if a slight modification to another, and it refers to that one. It’s not a _strong_ answer, but some edits could change that. Deserves to stand, in my opinion.

Comment: Hi @Ben you are right but at the time I left the comment the answer was only a pure Thanks. I'll delete my comment since it is now irrelevant ;-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt oh, didn't see the edit history. Thanks for suggesting the improvements!